# Python recursion attempt is not returning any value

Tags: python, recursion

I am wondering why it's not returning anything--I would expect it to return sum. I am fairly new to recursion, am I doing this all wrong?

```
def inc(sum,vec):
    if vec==[]:
        print "returning sum",sum
        return sum
    else:
       sum= sum+vec.pop(0)
       inc(sum,vec)

In [78]: s=inc(0,[6,7])
returning sum 13

In [79]: s
```

Comment: You have no `return` statement in your `else` clause.

Comment: `if vec==[]` block returns something. The other one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` block should have a `return inc(sum,vec)`.

Why? Take a look at this:

- `inc(0, [6, 7])` called

  - in `else` -> calling `inc(6, [7])`

    - in `else` -> calling `inc(13, [])`

      - in `if vec == []` -> returning `13` to previous caller
    - now `inc(13, []) == 13` *and that's all*, this value is not passed anywhere
  - `inc(6, [7])` doesn't return anything
- `inc(0, [6, 7])` doesn't return anything

BTW, `if vec == []` can be safely replaced with `if not vec` and `sum = sum + vec.pop(0)` - with `sum += vec.pop(0)` for more clarity (although this line might me altogether omitted, see below).

All in all, the code could look like this:

```
def inc(sum, vec):
    if not vec:
        return sum
    return inc(sum + vec.pop(0), vec)
```

What's more, you could've used a default value with the `sum` argument:

```
def inc(vec, sum = 0): # << right here
    if not vec:
        return sum
    return inc(vec, sum + vec.pop(0)) # change the argument position
```

With that the call to this function will be clearer:

```
inc(0, [6, 7]) # before
inc([6, 7])    # after
```

If you want a one-liner (might be a bit less readable, though):

```
def inc(vec, sum = 0):
    # return sum if vec is empty or the _result_ of a recursive call otherwise
    return sum if not vec else inc(vec, sum + vec.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have an implicit return. Many people seem to assume that languages that do not otherwise have an implicit return, have an implicit return while using recursion. This is not true. Avoid this common pitfall and fix your code like this

```
def inc(sum,vec):
    if vec==[]:
        print "returning sum",sum
        return sum
    else:
       sum = sum+vec.pop(0)
       return inc(sum,vec)
```